# Rewriting all URLs to a single PHP controller on nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I've a web server which has two PHP files, `index.php` and `controller.php`, the latter which handles all non-/ requests with a `p` (for page) parameter, e.g.

```
/controller.php?p=some_page
```

The following nginx configuration works nicely:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

However, I now want to clean up the URLs, and want `/` to go to `index.php` and `/some_page` to go to `/controller.php?p=some_page`.

Here's the new configuration I'm trying:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    # this is new, and makes index.php handle /
    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    # this is new, but doesn't work.
    location @rewrites {
        if ($uri ~* ^/([0-9a-z_]+)$) {
            set $page_to_view "/controller.php?p=$1";
            rewrite ^/([0-9a-z_]+)$ $scheme://$http_host/controller.php?p=$1 last;
        }
    }
}
```

The browser address bar shows this:

```
- http://localhost:8080/some_page                  (initial request)
- http://localhost:8080/controller.php?p=some_page (first redirect one second later)
- https://localhost/some_page/                      (final redirect another second later)
```

So, it ends up on a URL which doesn't have the original port, with a trailing slash, and using scheme `https`.

What can I do to fix it?

PS It would be a bonus if trailing slashes didn't matter (i.e. `localhost:8080/some_page` and `localhost:8080/some_page/` shows the same thing.

PS the port 8080 is just me locally testing via Docker, which maps container 80 to host 8080.

**Update:**

I've implemented Richard's answers, and tried the suggested `curl`:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/some_page
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.21.4
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2021 15:07:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Location: http://localhost/some_page/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note the lack of port 8080.

**Update 2:**

With nginx directive `absolute_redirect off;`, I get this:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/some_page
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.21.4
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2021 16:01:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /some_page/

$ curl -I http://localhost:8080/some_page/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.21.4
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2021 16:01:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
```

So, the question remains how a request to `/some_page/` can serve up the response from `/controller.php?p=some_page`

Answer (score 1):

A named location (e.g. `location @rewrites`) is usually invoked from the last element of a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}
```

In your `location @rewrites` block, the `if` statement is unnecessary, the `set` variable is unused, and the `rewrite` statement will provoke an external redirect.

Try:

```
location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/([0-9a-z_]+)$ /controller.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I tried some of the suggestions, but get Forbidden now. Repro repo at https://github.com/juanuys/fake-presskit but changing controller.php to sheet.php instead, so try http://localhost:8080/sheet.php?p=a_night_at_locke_manor and http://localhost:8080/a_night_at_locke_manor

Comment: Unfortunately, you still have two errors. @rewrites must be the **last** element of the `try_files` statement, and you need to remove `$scheme://$http_host` from your `rewrite` statement if you want an internal redirection.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still ends up on the 3rd link in my post above (https://localhost/some_page). Here's the version incorporating your suggestions: https://github.com/juanuys/fake-presskit/blob/master/default.conf#L14-L16

Comment: Use `curl -I http://localhost:8080/controller.php?p=some_page` to see what the server is actually returning. Maybe your controller is generating the final redirect.

Comment: I redirects to `http://localhost/some_page/` which has no port, and a trailing slash. I've updated the repo with a very simple controller.php for testing, to eliminate dodgy code.

Comment: A thought: If nginx is not listening on port 8080, it cannot know which port to use in the redirect. So, I will need to specify it explicitly?

Comment: I tried `absolute_redirect off;` and get 301 to `/some_page/` (not trailing slash) and calling the latter is forbidden.

Comment: Is `some_page` also a directory? Nginx will generate a 301 redirect to append a trailing `/` when it detects that the URL points to a directory.

Comment: Yes, it is. The controller will serve up some content from a directory matching the token in the `?p=<token>`.

Comment: I suppose I can move those directories to something like `/content/some_page` so nginx doesn't raise 403.

Comment: Right, we've gone from 403 to 404. So, if nginx gets `/some_page/`, how can I make it serve `controller.php?p=some_page` 's content?

Answer (score 0):

I've landed on a configuration which works with the original links, but also the pretty URLs I was aiming for.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location = / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~* {
        rewrite ^/([0-9a-z_]+)/?$ /controller.php?p=$1 last;
    }
}
```

The key seems to be to not use a named location for the rewrite, but just match "everything else" with `location ~*` if the request isn't for `/` or a PHP file.